# List all past publishes in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-express

Does anyone know if there is a way to get a list of dates of previous publishes for a project in Visual Studio Express?

I have a manually-maintained change log of all versions and the changes I've made, but I didn't note the dates (which I now realise I should have done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should answer here with how I resolved this in case anyone else comes looking for the solution.

It would appear that there isn't a nice solution to this, so what I did was use the Windows command line to dump a directory listing into a text file of the folder to which I publish all versions of my project thus:

```
dir path\to\application\"Application Files"\ >> filelist.txt
```

on the basis that each directory's creation timestamp is the publish date.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Look at the AfterPublish Target Name

As per your note:

A possible alternative is you could look at your recycling bin for deleted items?

Comment: That looks like it's useful for recording timestamps from now on, but I'm looking for a way to get publish dates for publishes that I've already done.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how would looking in the recycling bin help?